# Ensure popup / context menus appear on the same monitor as click that opened them

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, menu

When I click the little gear / power icon at the top right of my left monitor, I see this (without blur -- that's just an artefact of me pressing <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> and then having the menu try to dismiss while the image is being captured):

[image: ubuntu-wrong-monitor]

Of course, in my desktop setup the two monitors are not completely side-by-side and so this is somewhat annoying. I would prefer if context menus (opened by mouse actions) opened on the same monitor as my mouse. This of course occurs correctly on the right monitor.

This is with Ubuntu 14.04 (and with a Geforce GTX 960 + latest drivers [346.72], in case that is relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't really a perfect answer, updating to Ubuntu 14.10 fixed this for me. I imagine there are some packages that are part of the Ubuntu 14.10 install that could be manually installed on Ubuntu 14.04 to fix this behaviour; who knows which ones they are.